# How do I insert the results of a unix command into the tcsh CLI?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, tcsh

I often find myself wanting to create datestamped files and folders.

For example, I'd love to be able to create a folder with a yymmdd datestamp called "160408-projectA" by typing:

`mkdir <ctrl-;>-projectA`

I've tried using `` bindkey -cs '^;' '`date +%y%m%d | perl -pe chomp`' ``

... but it says "bad key spec ^;".  Even switching to another key, e.g. ^o, it errors out with "160408: Command not found.".

Is this possible with tcsh?

Comment: Ugh.  This sounds possible; you can probably figure it out.  However, note that if you have a list of numbers like 160408, there is a better approach than the semi-automation that you seek.  The better approach is to use programming skill to create full automation, reading from the list as needed.  Too often, people rush ahead with the first solution that they can see, instead of stepping back and thinking about what would be more ideal.  In theory, how automate-able is this?  If your series of steps is precisely defined, that can usually be done by a program.

Comment: Clarified that "160408" is a yymmdd datestamp.  @TOOGAM, not sure what "list" you're referring to.  And I tried to figure it out for quite awhile before asking here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> isn't possible.  Before going into why, let me discuss what is possible.

`` bindkey -s '^;' '`date +%y%m%d | perl -pe chomp`' ``

Just take the "c" off of your attempt to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, and it works fine.

The `tcsh` command probably does not support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>, which is a very sensible design, because tcsh is meant to work with a traditional Unix terminal (or some software which behaves similarly), and traditional Unix terminals don't support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>.

So, why don't Unix terminals support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>?

The main point for all of these <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> sequences was to provide an easy way to type/represent the first 32 ASCII characters because those characters do not have easily type-able characters.  The straight-forward equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> isn't all that challenging to type without the need of a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> sequence, which is why no special Ctrl character (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>) is commonly supported.

I will elaborate.  First, I'll note that much of this answer was made referencing some information I documented, about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Sequences, on my website at [][CyberPillar][: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Keyboard Sequences](http://cyberpillar.com/dirsver/1/mainsite/techns/hndldata/hndldata.htm#ctlkbseq).

One of the rules for Ctrl characters is that if you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press a character with an ASCII value of 63 through 95, you'll end up with the character that has 64 less of an ASCII value than the character you pressed.  (Yes, 64 is subtracted from 63, if applicable.  That gets discussed more later.)

Another rule is that if you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press a character with an ASCII value of 96 through 122, you'll end up with a character that is 96 less than the character that you typed.  As a result, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (upper-case letter) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> (lowecase letter) will end up with the same character.  That's why if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, you may see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> echoed back.  The terminal converts the ASCII 3 to a string representing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> when preparing the output message, ignoring the fact that you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to generate the ASCII 3.

<kbd>;</kbd> (Semi-colon) is ASCII 59, which is not ASCII 64 through 95 nor ASCII 96 through 122.  Therefore, the rules that were just specified (covering ASCII 63 through 122) do not provide any common interpretation for ASCII 59 (to cover <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>).

One value, which feels like an exception, is the commonly supported rule, which is for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd>.  If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> did have a common interpretation, then the common interpretation would probably follow the same pattern as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd>.  The <kbd>?</kbd> character is ASCII 63.  So subtracting 64 from 63 yeilds -1, which basically equates to 127 with an underflow condition, which can be ignored.  The result is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> keystroke combination effectively ends up adding 64, so 63 + 64 = 127.  ASCII 127 often corresponds to the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, which may be challenging to represent since the <kbd>Delete</kbd> has a common special behavior (which is to delete text).  So ASCII 127 may frequently benefit substantially by having a commonly supported <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> sequence.  This way, a person can type the ASCII 127 code relatively easily, by using the keyboard sequence.

Following that pattern (of adding 64), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> would result in ASCII 123 which is a left curly brace ("`{`").  People did not support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> as a common standard way of typing <kbd>{</kbd> since <kbd>{</kbd> has its own relatively-easy way to enter it on the keyboard (which is by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>).

Comment: Maybe a terminal issue, but with:

``bindkey -s ^o '`date +%y%m%d | perl -pe chomp`'``

... when I type "mkdir <ctrl-o>" it gives me:

``mkdir `date +%y%m%d | perl -pe chomp` ``

(I'm on OS X, RH6 does the same.)

Comment: Yeah, that's expected.  Then keep typing.  So `mkdir <ctrl-;>-projectA` becomes `mkdir ``date +%y%m%d | perl -pe chomp``-projectA` which results in creating the folder that you asked for.  It doesn't show the date on the command line, but it does exactly what you asked for.  You could also do: bindkey -s ^i '!`ls -t | tail -1!`' (replace !'s with backticks, which I can't seem to get quoted as desired in this comment)

Comment: Ah, ok, I was hoping it would execute the command then push the results onto the command line so I could see exactly what would be created before hitting enter.  The -c option for bindkey seems to be close, I seem to need a combination of the two.